# replaceSubview:with and ARC is releasing old view

Tags: cocoa, nsview

I have an issue when using [NSView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html)'s `replaceSubview:with:` method to swap out different views. The old view is released when the method is called, the docs state,

> This method causes oldView to be released; if you plan to reuse it, be
>   sure to retain it before sending this message and to release it as
>   appropriate when adding it as a subview of another NSView.

However, when using automatic reference counting (ARC) retain messages cannot be sent. Do the docs need to be updated, how can I use this method with ARC?

The views I am swapping exist all in the same nib and I do not have different view controllers. What is the preferred way of swapping out views and storing them for later use?

Comment: What's the implication of the old view being released?

Comment: Because the views are loaded from the nib I don't own them. Calling the method releases an object 'owned' by the nib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First store the old view for later use in a strong variable and then swap it out should prevent it from being released.

Comment: Is it OK to make an IBOutlet a __strong variable? This does solve the problem. Another solution that worked: I added an NSMutableArray instance variable and added the __weak IBOutlet instance variable to the array, this makes ARC increase the retain count +1.

Comment: Yes. There are issues that you need to take into account. Make sure you don't have any retain cycles and make sure to set things to set it to nil in your dealloc.

Comment: The actual solution I went for in the end: use a NSViewController to manage the views. Instead of adding the views as IBOutlet I add the view controllers and properties to my AppController.